# match all subitems in a string as different matches with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm, match

I have a string and need to end up with an object that count all apples for every name,  my struggle was to get separate match for each apple they took

In the part `<@Viktor><@Kate>took:apple::apple:` I want to get two matches instead of 1, and more if there would be more apples like `<@Viktor><@Kate>took:apple::apple::apple::apple:`

```
const message = 'I had :apple::apple::apple::apple: :apple:<@Viktor><@Kate>took:apple::apple: and later <@viktor> took again:apple:but not <@kate>';

const result {
     viktor: 3,
     kate: 2
}
```

used this to handle the problem, but it wasn`t accepted by the interviewer coz I used join&split later. The task was to solve this problem only with regexp.

```
function countGifts(text) {
    let result = {}
    let names = ['viktor', 'kate']
    names.forEach(name=>{
        let regex =  new RegExp(`(${name}).*?(:apple:)+`, "gi")
        result[name] = text.match(regex).join('').split(':apple:').length-1
    })
    return result
}
console.log(
    countGifts(message)
);
```

I`m new to regexp, and would appreciate alternative solutions and hints for articles with complex examples, coz all I found was pretty easy

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: desired output is the result object above

Comment: What are the rules to get multiple persons taking the same apple? For instance if `<@Viktor><@Kate>` was `<@Viktor> was talking to <@Kate>`, would the next apple still belong to both of them? Why (not)?

Comment: logic was that they separately took two apples

Comment: What I mean is: why does it work that way. Would they still each take two apples if it was `<@Viktor> was talking to <@Kate>` instead of `<@Viktor><@Kate>`? Why (not)?

Comment: can't grasp what you're asking, there is no "talking" part in the string, it was a question on the interview, so I don`t know why it structured this way

Comment: Does it have to be javascript?

Comment: if solution can be reproduced with js it`s okay

Comment: I'll try again. Apparently the apples that are listed after `<@Viktor><@Kate>` count for both persons. Why does it count for both of them? What is the syntax that makes this happen? And will it still happen when there are characters between those to tags? When would it no longer happen that way, and do the apples only count for Kate? Why does the apple that follows the second `<@Victor>` not count for Kate? What is the rule here?

Comment: You wrote in your question "I wanna get two matches instead of 1", but you haven't explained why.

Comment: it was the only string provided, rules: <@Viktor><@Kate> took count for both of them, if there would be one person <@Kate> took :apple::apple:, it'd cound only for her.  There wouldn't be any chars between name tags. Hope it helps)

Comment: Let me put it another way, can you use PHP or Python?

Comment: "I wanna get two matches instead of 1", it was needed it for my solution. if you can handle the whole problem without this, it will be helpful anyway.  PHP and Python is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that if multiple name tags follow each other with maybe some separation text, but not `:apple:`, they will all get the apples that follow. I will also assume that if a name tag is duplicated in such a list, the duplication will be ignored. So `<@Victor><@Victor> :apple:` would assign one apple to Victor, not two.

Here is one way to do that:

```js
function countGifts(text) {
    const result = {};
    let isCollecting = false;
    const names = new Set; // Those that will get apples
    for (const [_, name] of text.matchAll(/:apple:|<@(\w+)>/g)) {
        if (name === undefined) { // Add apple to current names
            isCollecting = false;
            for (const key of names) {
                result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (!isCollecting) names.clear(); // Start new list
            isCollecting = true;
            names.add(name.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const message = 'I had :apple::apple::apple::apple: :apple:<@Viktor><@Kate>took:apple::apple: and later <@viktor> took again:apple:but not <@kate>';

const result = countGifts(message);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use PCRE compatible regex (e.g. python with the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library, or PHP) you could use this regex (using viktor as a sample name):

```
(?:<@viktor>(?:<@)?+|\G(?<!^))(?:(?!<@).)*?:apple:
```

This will match:

- `(?:<@viktor>(?:<@)?+|\G(?<!^))` : **either**

  - `<@viktor><?` : literally `<@viktor>`, followed by
  - `(?:<@)?+` an optional start of a name tag; **or**
  - `\G(?<!^)` : the end of the previous match (alternate use of `\G` to match beginning of string disallowed by negative lookbehind)
- `(?:(?!<@).)*?` : a minimal number of characters, none of which are at the start of a name tag (a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed))
- `:apple:` : literally `:apple:`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pCWOpv/1)

Python usage:

```py
import regex

names = ['viktor', 'kate']
message = 'I had :apple::apple::apple::apple: :apple:<@Viktor><@Kate>took:apple::apple: and later <@viktor> took again:apple:but not <@kate>'

res = { name : len(regex.findall(fr'(?:<@{name}><?|\G(?<!^))(?:(?!<@).)*?:apple:', message, regex.I)) for name in names }
```

Output:

```
{
  'viktor': 3, 
  'kate': 2
}
```

PHP usage:

```php
$names = ['viktor', 'kate'];
$message = 'I had :apple::apple::apple::apple: :apple:<@Viktor><@Kate>took:apple::apple: and later <@viktor> took again:apple:but not <@kate>';

$res = [];
foreach ($names as $name) {
    preg_match_all("/(?:<@$name>(?:<@)?+|\G(?<!^))(?:(?!<@).)*?:apple:/i", $message, $matches);
    $res[$name] = count($matches[0]);
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [viktor] => 3
    [kate] => 2
)
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/O0IKl)

Comment: Here is a pure regex solution for PHP and Python